# Middleware on route level based on multiple user roles

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I have about 10 type of users role in [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware) application, where e.g.

```
  user_type_1 and user_type 4 are accessing url-1.
  user_type_7, user_type_5 and user_type 4 are accessing url-2.
  user_type_5, user_type_1, user_type_3 and user_type 6 are accessing url-3.
  ............................................
  ............................................
   n number of combination of routes. url according to user type.
```

My `route/web.php` file have about 1500 routes and currently not seperated as group using middleware. I have to restrict user for only urls that is authorized for that kind of user_type. Can you please suggest any better approach for doing this.

I had tried with making combination of url with middleware group like below, but after few work left this approach.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['middleware_user_type_1', 'middleware_user_type_2']], function () {
        Route::get('url-1', 'XYZController@someMethod');
    });
```

In this way request first goes to first middleware in array and if not valid user type then not try with second middleware.

Comment: did you try this inside your  controller's `__construct()` ? do you have roles and users properly configured to separately specify them in the middleware array? do you have **Laratrust**? or **Bouncer** or **Spatie**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement one middleware and pass user types to it.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['check_user_type:type_1,type_2']], function () {
        Route::get('url-1', 'XYZController@someMethod');
    });
```

Take a look how similar logic implemented in [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/src/Middlewares/RoleMiddleware.php) role middleware.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:super-admin|writer']], function () {
    //
});
```

Middleware then explodes roles string by the separator, and then check if the current user has any of the roles.

Comment: What would be the logic in middleware in this case. I think it will check auth user type in supplied user types.

Comment: I updated answer by adding an example to clarify it.

Comment: Thanks, This is working for me. Tried using some route.

Answer (score 0):

You can define middleware and roles in route group. Firstly you are define roles management in middleware.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['roles'], 'roles' => ['role_1','role_2], function () {
    Route::get('/index', [
        'uses' => 'ExampleController@index',
        'as'=> 'index'
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

out of the box you can implement Policies:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#creating-policies

Regards.